# Implementing System verilog’s $value$plusargs() system function in Specman E

Tags: system-verilog, specman, system-verilog-dpi

What is the equivalent syntax or implementation for System verilog‘s ***$value$plusargs*** option in Specman E ?

I am working in converting a source code from System verilog to Specman E, I am stuck with implementing $value$plusargs() system function in Specman E. How do I pass the arguments from command line or Makefile to the source code in Specman E ?.
Here is the System verilog sample code which I want to convert and implement in Specman E environment ,

```
    function load_testname();
        if($value$plusargs("test=%s",test_name_s)) begin 
          $display(“Running testcase is %s”,test_name_s); 
        end 
     endfunction
```

I may also need ***$test$plusargs()*** implementation in Specman E. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `$value$plusargs(...)`, there is the `sn_plusarg_value(arg: string): string` method. For `$test$plusargs(...)` there is `sn_plusarg_exists(arg: string): bool`.

You pass plusargs to Specman with the `+plusarg[=value]` command line argument.

***Examples***:

```
var test_name := sn_plusarg_value("test");
var number_i := sn_plusarg_value("number").as_a(int);
```